# Automatic line breaking for English

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking

I have c. 80 pages of English text that naturally contains (in)definite articles. The text is block-aligned. The problem is that **the article** sometimes **remains in the end of line** and the noun starts on another.

**Input 1:**

```
The more you get the better you'll see.
```

**Output 1:** (the `|` character represents the end of line)

```
 The  more  you  get  the|
 better you'll see.      |
```

From my point of view this is extremely unreadable. Thus I'd like to prevent this behavior. One possible way of doing so is using `~` instead of spaces.

**Input 2:**

```
The~more you get the~better you'll see.
```

**Output 2:** (the `|` character represents the end of line)

```
 The    more    you   get|
 the better you'll see.  |
```

However, changing the whole text (the, a, an, in, of, ...) seems impossible - so many words. **Question:** Can I add something to the preamble in order to achieve `~` behavior implicitly? I mean is there any package that makes that even without explicit `~`s?

Comment: Have you tried loading package `microtype`? That does a little bit of magic to your letters.

Comment: @Johannes_B not really but I tried it right now... no visible change, probably it requires some specific options? I briefly read the package documentation but it doesn't seem to deal with my problem, does it? Could you provide some example please?

Comment: I do believe that this is possible by some dirty hack (that probably has some caveats). But I would advise heavily against it! I personally think the breaking _is_ readable and typographically preferable.

Comment: I think i have misunderstood your question. I thought words were printing in the margin. In your example sentence, one would make a little pause when reading, but i don't think this is reason for hacking the typesetting. I would just leave it, to be honest.

Comment: @JBantje (Johannes_B) do you think so? As a non-native speaker this causes some trouble to me... However, the supervisor of my thesis advised me to watch out for this. I'll probably write some kind of script that makes the changes automatically. I was just curious whether some more elegant solution exists.

Comment: I am not a typographer by any means, but I never saw anyone recommending to use a non-breaking space in this case. I only use them for (academic) titles, dates, maybe units (but there is `siunitx` for that) and the typical `lemma~\ref{...}`.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and it would never occur to me to prevent a linebreak at that position, nor have I ever seen any suggestion that it should be avoided there. Is this applying the conventions of a different language to English?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in Czech, you can't break after a preposition e.g. `after~event`. I found some English typography guides that don't mention the articles at all. Therefore I'm going to write that to my supervisor. Anyway, thanks guys.